# Wcf serialization of member of type OBJECT

Tags: wcf, object, serialization

I have DataContract (BalanceClassificationAttribute), which have a field of object type.

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(string))]
[KnownType(typeof(long))]
[KnownType(typeof(int))]
[KnownType(typeof(uint))]
public class BalanceClassificationAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Value of searching attribute.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public Object Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

This field Value can be as string, long, int, uint

A added these attribytes

```
[KnownType(typeof(string))]
[KnownType(typeof(long))]
[KnownType(typeof(int))]
[KnownType(typeof(uint))]
```

but this DataContract doesn't work. What can I do more?

Comment: You need to add also `[KnownType(typeof(object))]`

Answer (score 0):

The primary intent of the [KnownTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) is to be handle type inheritance scenarios in soap message deserialization. You are attempting to use it as a way of performaning data conversion on primitive types. Your safest bet is to handle the data conversion of the value by a series of `TryParse` calls on the types you reference in the `KnownType` list.

Comment: Hi! You offer to leave this field as object? In this case the method (which use this DataContract) don't available in my WCF test client.

Comment: Actually, I'd recommend setting the property type to `string` since that would make it easier to use the various `TryParse` methods. What you do with the converted results is a design concern for your application but I would avoid using the `Object` type since it makes the actual type it contains opaque unless you use reflection.